# Pyspark Split array of 'key:value' string elements to a struct and extract some values when found

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, split, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame with this schema:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = false)
 |-- data_zone_array: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

It actually contains an array `data_zone_array` containing several more or less predictable string values (or none at all), where their keys and values are separated by `:`; looking like this `show(5)` output:

```
id  |   data_zone_array
1   |   ['name:john', 'surname:wick', 'group:a', 'group:b', 'group:c']
2   |   ['name:joe', 'surname:linda', 'surname:boss', 'group:d', 'group:b']
3   |   ['name:david', 'group:a', 'age:7']
4   |   ['name:mary', 'surname:gilles']
5   |   ['name:charles', 'surname:paul', 'group:d', 'group:b', 'group:c', 'age:6', 'unplanned_attribute_165:thisvalue']
```

I want to :

- Extract some of those values according to a list of keys (such as `name` and `surname`) - knowing that their destination types are predictable (`name` will always be a unique string and `surname` an array of strings)
- Place all other found attributes in a struct containing string arrays. Note that there will be unpredictable attributes such as `unplanned_attribute_165`.

It would give this kind of schema:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = false)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- surname: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- other_attributes: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- <attrx>: array (containsNull = true)  
 |    |    |-- element: string(containsNull = true) 
 |    |-- <attry>: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string(containsNull = true)
 |    |-- ......
```

With records like:

```
id  |   name        |   surname             |   other_attributes
1   |   'john'      |   ['wick']            |   {group:['a','b','c']}
2   |   'joe'       |   ['boss', 'linda']   |   {group:['b', 'd']}
3   |   'david'     |   <null>              |   {group: ['a'], age:['7']}
4   |   'mary'      |   ['gilles']          |   <null>
5   |   'charles'   |   ['paul']            |   {group: ['b','c','d'], age:['6'], unplanned_attribute_165:['thisvalue']}
```

Any idea on how to perform such operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing.

First, explode the column `data_zone_array` and extract keys and values into separate columns `key` and `value` by splitting on `:`.

Then, group by `id` and `key` and collect list of values associated with each key. And group by again by `id` to create map `key -> [values]`.

Finally, select keys you want as columns and filter the reste of the keys from the map using `map_keys` + `filter` + `transform` to create the `other_attributes` column.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1 = (df.withColumn("data_zone_array", F.explode("data_zone_array"))
       .withColumn("key", F.split("data_zone_array", ":")[0])
       .withColumn("value", F.split("data_zone_array", ":")[1])
       .groupBy("id", "key").agg(F.collect_list("value").alias("values"))
       .groupBy("id").agg(F.map_from_arrays(F.collect_list("key"), F.collect_list("values")).alias("attributes"))
       .select("id",
               F.col("attributes")["name"].alias("name"),
               F.col("attributes")["surname"].alias("surname"),
               F.expr("""transform(
                          filter(map_keys(attributes), k -> k not in('name', 'surname')),
                           x -> struct(x as key, attributes[x] as value)
                      )""").alias("other_attributes")
               )
       )

df1.show(truncate=False)
# +---+---------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |id |name     |surname      |other_attributes                                                        |
# +---+---------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |5  |[charles]|[paul]       |[{group, [d, b, c]}, {age, [6]}, {unplanned_attribute_165, [thisvalue]}]|
# |1  |[john]   |[wick]       |[{group, [a, b, c]}]                                                    |
# |3  |[david]  |null         |[{group, [a]}, {age, [7]}]                                              |
# |2  |[joe]    |[linda, boss]|[{group, [d, b]}]                                                       |
# |4  |[mary]   |[gilles]     |[]                                                                      |
# +---+---------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. 

I actually came across this way of doing for the early stages but there's something that bothers me: the combination of `explode` and `collect_list` might induce a serious performance issue in my opinion (pull me up if I am wrong). 
As `data_zone_array` contains in reality more than 15 different attributes, it would multiply the number of rows in the resulting dataset by at least 15 (more if there are different values for the same attribute) for an initial dataset of 1M lines to transform quickly. And the subsequent aggregation is an heavy operation as well.

Comment: I have actually tested this solution and works well ! 
I am just wondering if in the `other_attributes` array it would be possible to have a `struct` (key, value) of `array` instead of an `array` of `struct` (key,value).
Such as `{group: [d,b,c], age: [6]}` instead of `[{key:group, value:[d,b,c]}, {key:age, value:[6]}]`